# Explain the output of c Program

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a=3;

  printf("%d"+1,a);
  return 0;
}
```

Why is the output of this program is **"d"**?
And if this int specifier (%d) is replaced by float (%f) then it gives output as **"f"**.

Please explain this code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%d" + 1` is the same as `&"%d"[1]`, i.e. a pointer to the second character in the string. `printf` starts interpreting the string from there on as the format specifier, which is thus the same as just `"d"` (and the second argument is simply ignored).